# What do colons in python do when placed after an array?

Tags: python, numpy

Any idea what colons is supposed to be doing in this case?
I just stumbled upon this and saw that it doesn't produce any error, I got curious to see if it did anything. So far I don't see colons doing anything in this case.

Can somebody enlighten me?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1, 10)
x
output: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

x:5
x
output: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

[image]

Comment: That is called a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @Jab is right. Maybe what you are looking for is `x[:5]`

Answer (score 3):

As the comments say you might be looking for [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) but actually this is no longer a `SyntaxError`. You are giving variable `x` a type annotation of `5` (which doesn't really make any sense to actually do).

You can look in the `__annotations__` of your module to see it has been added there e.g.

```
print(__annotations__)
x : 5
print(__annotations__)
```

will print

```
{}
{'x': 5}
```

For more details on variable annotations see [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/).